# How can I fix the vscode debuger in VSCode?

Tags: go, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug a simple Golang code in VSCode with dvl-dap and I get the following error:

[image]

Does anybody know how can I solved this issue?

I'm working from a remote vm using the extension Remote - SSH.

Comment: The error info is `closing connection from different user`, please provide more details about your environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm adding this for reference in case someone else faces this issue.

The fix was merged/released on [v1.7.1](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/compare/v1.7.0...v1.7.1), but I'm remote debugging on v1.8.3 and still hitting that problem.

One possible workaround is to disable the 'same user' check in your VSCode settings.json, like this

```
go.delveConfig": {
    "debugAdapter": "dlv-dap",
    "dlvFlags": ["--only-same-user=false"],
    [...]
}
```

and then just let VSCode use a default launch.json to run delve remotely and attach your local client -- in the project where I've tested this I haven't even defined a custom launch.json.

Comment: You can also use the only-same-user parameter in your cli command: `dlv debug ./main.go --headless --listen=127.0.0.1:12345 --accept-multiclient --continue --only-same-user=false` to prevent the following error message when connecting: `closing connection from different user (127.0.0.1:33976): connections to localhost are only accepted from the same UNIX user for security reasons` (i started the dlv server in wsl2 and attached from vscode studio under windows to the running dlv server)

Answer (score 0):

That was reported initially in [`golang/vscode-go` issue 1555](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1555):

```
>> accepted connection from client
-> server: {"type":"request","seq":1,"command":"initialize","arguments":{"adapterID":"go","linesStartAt1":true,"columnsStartAt1":true,"pathFormat":"path"}}
<- server: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:40535\n2021-06-09T02:26:51Z debug layer=dap DAP server pid = 12574\n"}}
<- server: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"stderr","output":"2021/06/09 02:26:51 sameuser_linux.go:114: closing connection from different user (127.0.0.1:52544): connections to localhost are only accepted from the same UNIX user for security reasons\n"}}
<- server: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"2021-06-09T02:26:51Z error layer=dap Error accepting client connection: Only connections from the same user that started this instance of Delve are allowed to connect. See --only-same-user.\n2021-06-09T02:26:51Z debug layer=dap DAP server stopping...\n2021-06-09T02:26:51Z debug layer=dap DAP server stopped\n"}}
<- server: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"console","output":"connection error: Error: read ECONNRESET\n"}}
<- server: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"terminated"}
```

With the main error message being:

```
sameuser_linux.go:114: closing connection from different user (127.0.0.1:52544):
connections to localhost are only accepted from the same UNIX user for security reasons
```

It is fixed in a fork of delve: [`suzmue/delve` commit 5137515](https://github.com/suzmue/delve/commit/513751573ea101f1d0f9373ed9b02fb716bfe566), but said patch might not have been yet integrated to  [go-delve/delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve): its [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) does not yet list "service: fix sameuser check".
Still, make sure you are using the latest delve 1.7.2.